# Auto-completion of \ref doesn't work for my counter

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, auto-completion

I defined a counter and a command that defines examples and labels them.
Unfortunately, when I use these definitions the `\ref` is not autocompleted by the texmaker or sharelatex.

What should I add in the definitions that the editor becomes aware of the existing labels?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{examples}[section]
\renewcommand\theexamples{\arabic{section}.\arabic{examples}}

\newcommand{\xampl}[2]{\refstepcounter{examples}\par\medskip\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{14mm}@{}l@{}}%
(\theexamples) & #1\\
\end{tabular}\label{#2}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\xampl{The sentence is the first example}{l1}
\xampl{The sentence is the 2nd example}{l2}

\ref{l1}, \ref{l2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The editor or sharelatex rely on parsing the code, and since it is not explicitly see `\label` it does not now about these labels. It is probably a better idea to remove the `\label` from the macro definition and adding it manually. You probably have a similar problem with interfaces where the label is set using `label=...`

Comment: Thanks. If you make a proper answer from this comment, I will accept it.

Comment: Off-topic: To play it safe, you may want to add a `\par` directive immediately after `\end{tabular}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most editors (including sharelatex) provides auto completion for labels by parsing the source code for explicit `\label{...}`, so when you hide `\label` inside a macro, the label is no longer picked up by the parser.

The best solution is probably to not include `\label` in the macro definition and use something like

```
\xampl{The sentence is the first example}
\label{l1}
```

instead. This also make the source code easier to read.

The editors have a similar problem when an interface is setting `\label` through a key-value interface. For example the interface provided by the `listings` package.